# Python Regex: replace text only if not contained between specific characters

Tags: python, regex

```
Example text: blah blah <a href="/Prevage+MD">Prevage MD</a> xxx yyy zzz Prevage asdf
```

I want to replace "Prevage" only if it is not contained between `<` and `>` tags. For the example text above, only the last `Prevage` should be matched and replaced by the replacement string, `<a href="/Prevage">Prevage</a>`.

I think this requires the use of a negative lookahead `(?!<|>)` and a negative lookbehind `(?<!<|>)`, but my regex `(?<!<|>)(.)prevage(?!<|>)` doesn't work: it matches all 3 `Prevage`s.

[Link to regex](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C!%3C%7C%3E)(.)prevage(%3F!%3C%7C%3E)&test_string=blah%20blah%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2FPrevage%2BMD%22%3EPrevage%20MD%3C%2Fa%3E%20xxx%20yyy%20zzz%20Prevage%20asdf&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Desired output:

```
blah blah <a href="/Prevage+MD">Prevage MD</a> xxx yyy zzz <a href="/Prevage">Prevage</a> asdf
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a proper HTML parser like Beautiful Soup?

Comment: @bard it would match also the `Prevage` present inside the `a` tag.

Comment: @senshin I couldn't find any Beautiful Soup examples for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Coming up with a regex which matches the inverse of a pattern is tricky. In this case it is helpful to express both what you do and don't want to match in the positive, then change the replaced value based on which of them was matched.

For example:

```
import re

text = '''Example text: blah blah <a href="/Prevage+MD">Prevage MD</a> xxx yyy zzz Prevage asdf'''

def replace(m):
    tag, = m.groups()
    if tag:
        return tag
    else:
        return 'XXX'

print re.sub('(<.*?>)|Prevage', replace, text)
```

Which prints:

```
Example text: blah blah <a href="/Prevage+MD">XXX MD</a> xxx yyy zzz XXX asdf
```

However, note that this will not work as expected when it encounters nested HTML tags. For a complete solution you should consider using an HTML parsing library.

Comment: It looks like he doesn't want the one within the `<a>` replaced. What about `(<.*?>(.*?</.*?>)?|Prevage`?

Comment: Yeah that'll do it. Better yet `(<.*?>(?:.*?</.*?>)?`.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is a reasonable place to use non-capturing groups, I guess.